# NPE accessing Application method from AlerDialog OnClick method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-alertdialog

Building on a theme from yesterday...I'm getting an NPE accessing a method in a singleton Application class from within an AlertDialog.

Activity SavedMealsActivity sets OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals as the listener for a series of TextViews in a ScrollView. OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals is defined as a separate class.

OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals displays an AlertDialog which gives the option of going to a different Activity, but it first needs to fire the methods of an Application class which is defined as a singleton (MealTimerApplication). This is the first line of the onClick method (line 25 in the first code sample below), and it throws the NPE because the activity is null at the time.

I've tried passing in the activity from the calling Activity (SavedMealsActivity) but for some reason it's not working as I'd hoped. Any ideas?

OnLongClick listener class - OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals:

```
public class OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals implements OnLongClickListener {
    Context context;
    String id;
    private Activity activity;

    public OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context = context;
        id = view.getTag().toString();

        final CharSequence[] items = { "Edit", "Delete" };
        //Set activity to allow context to be used in the OnClickListener/onClick method below
        this.activity = activity;

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Meal Item")
                .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            //Set the global meal_id variable and invoke the MealActivity
                            ((MealTimerApplication) activity.getApplication()).setMealId(Long.getLong(id));
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(),MealActivity.class);
                            activity.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                        }
                        else if (item == 1) {

                            boolean deleteSuccessful = new TableControllerMeal(context).delete(id);

                            if (deleteSuccessful){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Record was deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to delete record.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            ((SavedMealsActivity) context).readRecords();

                        }

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }).show();

        return false;
    }
```

Calling Activity - SavedMealsActivity:

```
public class SavedMealsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_meals);

        //Read saved meal records from the database and display them
        readRecords();

    }
    public void readRecords() {
        LinearLayout linearLayoutRecords = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRecords);
        linearLayoutRecords.removeAllViews();

        List<meal> meal = new TableControllerMeal(this).read();

        if (meal.size() > 0) {

            for (meal obj : meal) {

                long id = obj.id;
                String MealDesc = obj.meal_desc;
                int MealMinutes = obj.meal_ready_time;

                String textViewContents = MealDesc + " - ready at "
                        + Utilities.formatTime(MealMinutes);

                TextView textViewItem = new TextView(this);
                textViewItem.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
                textViewItem.setText(textViewContents);
                textViewItem.setTag(Long.toString(id));

                textViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals(this));

                linearLayoutRecords.addView(textViewItem);
            }

        }

        else {

            TextView Item = new TextView(this);
            Item.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            Item.setText("No records yet.");

            linearLayoutRecords.addView(Item);
        }
    }
```

Application class:

```
public class MealTimerApplication extends Application {
    private static MealTimerApplication singleton;
    private long mealId = 0;

    // Returns the application instance
    public static MealTimerApplication getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    public final void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
    }

    public void setMealId(long mealId) {
        this.mealId = mealId;
    }

    public long getMealId() {
        return this.mealId;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at com.ian.mealtimer.OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals$1.onClick(OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals.java:39)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-28 16:48:03.637: E/AndroidRuntime(4241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's on OnLongClickListenerSavedMeals.java line 39?

Comment: Line 39 is intentionally blank ;0)

Comment: Sorry my mistake - line 39 is "((MealTimerApplication) activity.getApplication()).setMealId(Long.getLong(id));"

Comment: (it's the 25th line in the first code sample as I trimmed the imports etc from the top)

Comment: Unrelated, but shouldn't you be using `parseLong(id)` instead of `getLong(id)`?

Comment: ashishduh - yes - thanks! Anyone have any ideas re. the main problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get NPE because of autoboxing. [Long.getLong(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29) is not what you actually you need, check its description:

> > Returns the Long value of the system property identified by string.

It definitely returns null in your case. Moreover it returns null reference to `Long` object, but your `MealTimerApplication.setMealId`  expects argument with primitive type `long`. Here is the point where auto-boxing implicitly trying to cast your `Long` object returned by `getLong` method to the `long` primitive. But as value was null auto-boxing fails and you get NPE.

You should just use [Long.valueOf(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29) instead of `Long.getLong(String)`.

Comment: Thanks Andrei and ashishduh - this was indeed what was causing the NPE